# Cannot make image responsive in mobile even with width 100% and height auto

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I've been looking up online for hours on how to make the image responsive on mobile..This is what it looks like on computer:

[image]

When I try 'inspect element' and view the images, it comes out like this:

[image]

As shown, the images are big squished(?) where width is being decreased.

I'm using media query to customize the width and height.

HTML:

```
<div id = "projects">
        <div id = "we-cycle">
            <img id = "we-cycle-image" src = "./photos/we-cycle.png" width = "100%" height = "auto">
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#projects {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 300px auto;
    margin-left: -30px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#we-cycle-image {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #we-cycle-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your problem.. It doesn't look like your code posted here is the source of the problem. Furthermore your `<img ..>` code is not valid HTML. Have a look at the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). `width` and `height` HTML attributes should only contain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

yeah so the images are being squished because their aspect ratio is 1:1 or square but in small screens theres not enough space for them to be in a square form so the browser is changing the aspect ratio to something that would fit even though it doesn't look good
quick fix: assuming you already have the images in a div with a display of flex, add the following style:
`flex-wrap: wrap;`